# Set Theory Proof-Check: Problem Involving Axiom Schema of Comprehension

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, axioms

Problem: "Show the intersection of a class and a set is a set;" and it comes from material covering the axiom schema of comprehension.

I'm using the axiom schema of comprehension as it's listed on Wikipedia and my class notes; that is,

$$\forall w_{1},...,w_{n} \forall A \exists B \forall x (x \in B \iff [x \in A \land \varphi(x,w_{1},...,w_{n})]),$$
or in words, "Given any set $A$, there is a set $B \subseteq A$ such that, given any set $x$, $x \in B$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $\varphi$ holds for $x$."

My attempt at a solution:

---

Let $S$ be a set. Let $C= \{ x| \varphi(x,y_{1},...,y_{n}) \}$ be the class containing all sets $x$ such that the formula $\varphi(x,y_{1},...,y_{n})$ holds. By the axiom schema of comprehension, for our formula $\varphi$ and our arbitrary set $S$, there exists a set $T \subseteq S$ such that for all sets $z$, $$z \in T \; \text{ iff } \; z \in S \text{ and } \varphi(z,y_{1},...,y_{n}).$$ Define $T= \{s \in S | \varphi(s,y_{1},...,y_{n}) \}$.
If $T= \emptyset$, then $T$ is a set. If $T$ is nonempty, then there exists some $t \in T$. Since $t \in T$, we have $t \in S$. Note also that we have $t \in C$ by definition of $C$ (that is, $t$ is some set fulfilling our formula $\varphi$). Hence $t \in T$ if and only if $t \in S$ and $t \in C$. Therefore the set $T \subseteq S$ is the intersection of the arbitrary set $S$ and arbitrary class $C$.

---

My problem is that while understanding the axiom schema of replacement is one thing... *using* it absolutely correctly is something else (unfortunately, most advanced math books don't come overly equipped with examples on these sorts of things.)

A main concern is that I properly employed the formula $\varphi$. Was I correct in assigning it to some arbitrary class $C$, and then saying 'for any set $S$, there must also be a subset $T$ for which $\varphi$ holds true for every member of $T$'?

To any set theory minded folks, what improvements would you make?  How you would grade such a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning looks good to me, but a couple of questions:
1. What kind of system of Set Theory are you working with in your course? ZF, Von Neumann-Bernays-Gödel?
2. Have you formally defined the intersection of a class and a set?

I see no problem in defining an arbitrary class by an arbitrary formula, and so to use this same formula as to define a subset of an arbitrary set. Good job!